# Best expression for place where dogs are born, something like maternity ward is for humans

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the expression for the place where dogs are born? Could I say that we have a breeding station with canine maternity kennels or maternity ward? I want something like what maternity ward is for humans.

Comment: "Best" in what sense? Best for an advertisement offering the service? Best  legislative term?

Comment: Im translating a story about a guide puppy and how volunteers established a breeding station with a "maternity ward/clinic/kennels"?

Comment: Well, if it's a translation, one would want to know something about the term in the original. Was it a term a child would understand? Was it breeder-jargon?

Comment: I am looking rather for a breeder jargon word.

Comment: Is it for  many litters simultaneously?

Comment: @TimRomano Yes, a building where "whelping boxes" are placed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call the building(s)  where many whelping boxes can be placed such that the individual litters are kept separate from one another but remain readily accessible to staff a *whelping facility*.

Comment: +1, A whelping facility is designed to protect puppies during birth.

Answer (score 4):

A brief time spent on the google finds that the containers are called "whelping boxes."

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about being the best (though it's certainly unusual), but how about a "**puppy crèche**" or "**canine crèche**"?

> [**crèche**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/creche) *noun*: 4. *Ethology* an assemblage of dependent young animals that are cared for communally. see, the Free Dictionary

Comment: Note that this would mean something different in the UK and Ireland, where _creche_ means ‘daycare’ or even ‘kindergarten’, i.e., the place parents send their children off to during the day when they’re at work. A _puppy creche_ would likely be understood as puppy kennels there.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - it could be adapted and adopted, hey?

Comment: I think that bitches are proprietarily protective of their litters, so I don't think that the communal caring part is apt.

Comment: Yeah, but that's because you like "whelping boxes" better @deadrat

Answer (score 0):

Whelping box is the equivalent of the birth room/bed as well as becomes the "nursery" for the next few weeks. Often these boxes have something called "pig rails" along the edges for the puppies to fit under but jutting out from the wall enough that the dam cannot squish the puppy accidentally. There are various other features to them that make them ideal for the birth and care of young puppies such as a gate that can be lowered or raised to keep the puppies in the box when they start tottering around.